# Why strtotime returns false?

Tags: php, date, strtotime

```
if(strtotime($date_in)==false){
    echo $date_in." wtf?";
}
```

Output:

> 2012-05-12 wtf?

Why does  `strtotime($date_in)` return `false`?

Comment: It depends on the value on $date_in

Comment: If you are checking for false, always use the `===` operator.

Comment: Take a look at the allowed date/time formats: http://de.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php

Comment: You almost certainly have more characters in your input string than you think, my money is on leading/trailing non-numeric characters. Please show the *exact* output of `var_dump($date_in);`

Comment: Using your examples from your question [it works fine for me](http://codepad.org/JLDNAOPU) - i suggest the input isnt what you think it is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
if(strtotime($date_in)===false){
    echo "[$date_in] wtf?";
}
```

If testing for `false` always use the `===`. Also wrapping the `$date_in` variable with brackets help you see if there is any whitespace.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: thx a lot it was a whitespace i did $date_in=trim($date_in) and all is ok.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried to replicate this issue, with success, but only after I changed the default timezone to:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Brussels');
```

so, perhaps you could check your ini file, or use `date_timezone_get` and make sure the your settings know how to deal with the date format you're using?

Alternatively, or if the php.ini is off limits for some reason, you could look into the [datetime object](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php).

Comment: Thx all for response it was whitespace in $date_in variable. I fill $date_in with value from database (date field in mysql). Don`t know why it returned whitespace but that was the problem.

Comment: damn, thought about suggesting `trim()` - perhaps check if the field in your DB is set as varchar - with spacefill?